# Message error from Symfony4 when asking for actor_show with a function generate with a slug

Tags: regex, symfony4

I can't succeed to resolve this error message by myself even after research on the web:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "slug" for route "actor_show" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

I suppose that it's because my regex is not well defined but I have no more idea to do it well...

Here is the demand for the function generate():
All special characters are processed:
- à, ç, etc. become a, c, etc; !, apostrophes and other punctuation is deleted;
- Spaces at the beginning and end of strings are removed;
- There are not several - successive;
- The generated string is in lowercase

This is my function generate()

```
class Slugify
{
    public function generate(string $slug) : string
    {
        // lowercase
        $slug = strtolower($slug);
        // transliterate
        $slug = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $slug);
        // remove duplicate -
        $slug = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $slug);
        // remove spaces
        $slug = preg_replace('^\s+|\s+$', '', $slug);
        // remove punctuation
        $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '', $slug);
        return $slug;
    }
}
```

This is a part of my twig template:

```
       {% for actor in actors %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ actor.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('actor_show', {'slug': actor.slug}) }}">Accéder</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('actor_edit', {'slug': actor.slug}) }}">Modifier</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('actor_delete', {'slug': actor.slug}) }}">Supprimer</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Aucun acteur trouvé</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{ path('actor_new') }}">Créer un nouveau</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The pattern `[^/]++` matches at least 1 times any char except a `/` and the message is `"" given`. Are you sure the string is not empty? Note that `[^a-z0-9-]` also matches a space, and that is replaced with an empty string. Perpaps use `[^a-z0-9\s-]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My code still doesn't work, I suppose it comes from another point. I'm going to find it !!